# Error in Javascript multiple Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why the output is different from my Code data?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var array = [];
            var innerArray = [];

            var innerDataArray= [];

            innerDataArray['a']="a";
            innerDataArray['b']="b";

            innerArray.push(innerDataArray);

            innerDataArray['a']="c";
            innerDataArray['b']="d";

            innerArray.push(innerDataArray);

            array = innerArray;

            console.info(array);

        });
```

the data in array is  "c","d","c","d".

Why the output is different from my Code data?

Comment: Arrays in javascript are passed as references, and you modify the same `innerDataArray` array twice.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in javascript are passed as references, and you modify the same `innerDataArray` array twice.

Just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var array = [];
    var innerArray = [];

    innerArray.push({"a": "a", "b": "b"});
    innerArray.push({"a": "c", "b": "d"});

    array = innerArray;

    console.info(array);
});
```

or even simpler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var array = [];

    array.push({"a": "a", "b": "b"});
    array.push({"a": "c", "b": "d"});

    console.info(array);
});
```

also, as @TJCrowder says, if you set non-numeric keys in an array, it is automatically turned into a plain object.

Comment: You might want to flag up that you changed what used to be `innerDataArray` from an array to a non-array object. Also, if you're going to assign to `array` at the end, there's no point in initializing it with an array that you're going to throw away.